# Searching First Name and Lastname

Tags: java, sql, database, prepared-statement

When I input a letter in my textfield it is searching through the first_name of my table.

Is it possible for it to search the last_name also?

```
String sql1 = "SELECT * FROM members  WHERE f_name  LIKE ?";
ps = con.prepareStatement(sql1);
ps.setString(1,"%" +tf_search.getText().trim() + "%");
rs=ps.executeQuery(); 
table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

Comment: With the same value, you want to search in both ? Then add an `or last_name = ?` and the second parameter in the preparedStatement.

Comment: Please note: you should not put irrelevant tags on your question. You are asking how to query your database. That has nothing to do where your strings are coming from or going to!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For first name search only:

```
String sql1 = "SELECT * FROM members  WHERE f_name  LIKE ?;
```

For last name search only:

```
 String sql1 = "SELECT * FROM members  WHERE l_name LIKE ?";
```

For both:use AND || OR as to your need.

```
  String sql1 = "SELECT * FROM members  WHERE f_name  LIKE ? and(or) l_name LIKE ?";
```

Note:
It's just SQL basic and you should learn it first I suggest.

Comment: I updated my answer, it's not possible for only with one query, plz do your search input filed condition first and use correct query.

Comment: Sir thanks for your help i think i've found a solution your comment is really helpful thanks :)

Comment: Glad to hear!Great!

Comment: i have to use OR for it to search for both

Comment: you know what you need now, but be careful your condition in service layer